# Google Calculator from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, calculator

I'm working on a simple Javascript app, and I need a way to take a string an determine a value by entering it into a calculator. (i.e. if the string is "pi^2 sqrt(3)" you'll get 17.0946563")

Rather than reinventing the wheel, I was hoping there was a way to implement Google's calculator to grab the result. Basically, I want to call http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q= followed by the string, and have Google output the result. The only example I've seen is the one [here](http://www.dynamicguru.com/php/currency-conversion-using-php-and-google-calculator-api/) but it's in PHP. I don't know much PHP, so I was wondering if there was any way to either call the PHP function from within Javascript or implement the function directly with Javascript. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a library like jQuery to make an AJAX call to grab and parse the results. You'll need to build up the URL yourself and, if using jQuery, call the [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

Comment: Are you sure the $.getJSON method works in this situation? I understand the examples, and I can get them working easily, but when I try running it with Google's URL, it doesn't even reach the success function. Unless by build up the URL myself you mean create a page on my own server to call. How would I go about doing this?